# family permit direct family member how to appeal

Tags: visa-refusals

I am an Irish citizen and applied for a family permit for my mother-in-law as a  direct dependant family member. And this was the decision made by the clearance officer

THE DECISION:

- You state that your son in law ........ is an Irish national.You have provided evidence that your sponsor holds an Irish passport

  -You state that you are a dependent direct family member of your sponsor,however you have failed to provide any evidence of your relationship to your sponsor.

I really do not understand the decision for the refusal because I sent my wife's birth certificate showing her as my mother in-law ,our marriage certificate,pictures, affidavit of change of name and news paper publication of change of name.All the documents showing dependency was submitted. 
I need guidance on what to do .
Thanks in heaps

Comment: Please scan and attach the entire letter, having blocked out or redacted the personal information (passport number, name, address, etc) contained in the letter.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear where you are applying, but I will assume you are applying to the UK under the EEA family permit program.

This program is only for the following categories of relations (see [this website](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility) for more information):

> You must be the EEA citizen’s spouse or civil partner, or related to
>   them (or their spouse or civil partner) as their:
>
> - child or grandchild under 21 years old, or dependent child or
>     grandchild of any age
> - dependent parent or grandparent

Your in-laws only qualify if they are dependent on your spouse; for example, they are retired and are supported by your spouse.

If not, then your in-laws have to apply as a normal visitor visa. They can still be sponsored by you.

You also don't need to supply "extra" things such as name change and newspaper clippings, these can work against you as they can seem as if you are being deceptive.

It just seems you have applied for the wrong visa category.

Comment: The EEA family permit is a UK document; given the question's title the only reasonable conclusion is that this concerns the UK.  Also, the in-laws can be dependent on the spouse or the EEA sponsor.  Also, "you have failed to provide any evidence of your relationship to your sponsor" is clearly not consistent with the application having included the birth and marriage certificates.  If there was no evidence of dependence then the refusal should have said so.  So an appeal or administrative review may in fact be in order.

Comment: It may not be clear from the documents that the in-laws are _dependents_ which is a clear requirement. Just because they are in-laws, doesn't qualify them for the family permit. They can visit easily on a normal visit visa.

Comment: But if they are in fact dependent then the answer is to continue to pursue the family permit, not to apply for a visitor visa.